# TFVC binding with Website project

Tags: angular, version-control, azure-devops, tfvc

I am working on a angular 4 project and using VS code as an editor. Unfortunately I am using TFVC as source control for this project and I am facing TFVC binding issue. I have following questions,

1) Currently, I have created a WEBSITE project (not web application) in visual studio 2015 and checking-in/checking-out using TFVC. Do I have to add an solution file in TFVC ??

2)  If I add an new folder (folder is not empty, has sub folders and files) than it does not reflect in TFVC PENDING CHANGES list. What am I missing ?  Currently I have to go to solution explorer and add each folder and file explicitly into the TFS.

Earlier I was using Git for my angular app so it was straight forward but have not used TFVC to maintain UI app.

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT , I was out during x-mas. I am going to check today and will post the result. really appreciate your follow-up.

Comment: @starian chen-MSFT , it worked. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add the solution file to source control (TFVC) in order to build it through TFS/VSTS build system or open it in Visual Studio directly.

By default, the solution file will be in user folder (e.g. `C:\Users\XXX \Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebSite2`) and uses absolute path of web site, I recommend that you can copy it to the same or parent folder of web site, you can change the path to the relative path in solution file manually or refer to these steps below to create web site:

1. File > New > Project
2. Select other Project Types >Visual Studio Solutions > Blank Solution
3. Right click solution > Add > New Web Site
4. Change the location (e.g. [solution path][web site name])
5. Right click solution in Visual Studio > Add solution to source control

Secondly, I think you created/added the files in file system instead of through Visual Studio, refer to these steps to add files to pending changes:

1. Team Explorer > Pending Changes
2. Click Detected link

[image]

3. Check the files and click Promote button, then the related files will be added to Included Changes and you can check in.